# Flutter call storage value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple dart file where I define the colors etc.

Issue is I need to get values from Fluttersecure storage.

Like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';


final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

String _TaxPercentTaxPercent = await storage.read(key: "_TaxPercentTaxPercent");
String _DeliveryCharges = await storage.read(key: "_DeliveryCharges");



String priceGlobal = 'PKR ';
int TaxGlobal = 12;
double discount = 0.8;
int DeliveryGlobal = 50;
// Background and Card Color
const kPrimaryColor = Color(0xFF3c80e3);
const kBackgroundLightColor = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
const kBackgroundDarkColor = Color(0xFF121212);
const kErrorLightColor = Color(0xFFB00020);
const kErrorDarkColor = Color(0xFFCF6679);
const kCardDarkColor = Color(0xFF242529);
const kCardImageBCColor = Color(0xffF5F5F5);

// Font Color
const kPrimaryLightFontColor = Color(0xFF1F1F1F);
const kSecondaryLightFontColor = Color(0xFF9098B1);
const kPrimaryDarkFontColor = Color(0xFFF0F0F0);
const kSecondaryDarkFontColor = Color(0xFF969696);

// Variant Color
var kYellowColor = Color(0xFFFFCC00);

var kBlackColor = Color(0xFF223263);
var kGreyColor = Color(0xFF9098B1);
```

The issue is I can't use await its showing an error

```
The await expression can only be used in an async function.
```

I need to know how can I set local store value. I don't have any function or anything in this file.

Comment: The error message is pretty much self-explanatory, you can't use `await` outside an `async` function. Put it inside one

Comment: @HTMHell but I am not using any function class or state. Its simple hardcoded values what will do if I need to call it?

Comment: Hard-coding values outside of a class is not an ideal practice in itself. If you are using packages that use device IO, they typically need to be asynchronous. They can't be called otherwise. You will need to implement an async method that can set the value once it's available.

Comment: You can't await a future in class body, make a function that is marked as async gets the data from storage for you. like async void readDataFromStorage(string key) { return await storage.Read(key); }

Answer (score 1):

You've followed the instrustions from pub.dev. NICE!
However, int the *Readme* page, it's actually the abstract of the code, which gives you some general sense, When you want to see how to really implements such function, read the code in the *example* page.

1. You get the await error because you can't use await outside an async function. Seems like it's an async process to read, write, delete etc. using this package.
2. **I have no idea what you are going to do with all these const, if you plan to use these const colors in your project and save it just for convience, why use Fluttersecure storage? just create a file called constants in lib (or lib/constants/colors.dart if you prefer) and import the file, I think it's the best and most common way to store constants such as color and fontSize.**
3. I've never use such packages before but from the documents, it seems that it's provide API to store data in secure, as the documents describes, you may have to write something and then use the read value to read it. Consider the code here https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage/example.